# Only showing element only within the certain div id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show a fixed image in another div but when only when scrolling within a certain div id or else I want it to hide it. I got it to show however my problem is it doesn't hide once I've left the div id.

```
 jQuery(document).on('scroll', function() {
           if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()>=jQuery('#theimeline').position().top){

               jQuery( "#Layer_1_time" ).show();
           }

       })

       });
```

Comment: Hi Omar, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to the [following page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better understanding of asking questions, so that it will be easier for us to tackle your problems. Please elaborate on what you mean by "once I have left the div id".

Comment: do u want to show a div and hide a div based on the scrolling in a inner div.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to check if the given element is visible in the view. Call this method every time the scroll event is triggered and respond correspondingly.

In the below example, the image is hidden/shown every time the div with text `trigger div` disappears or appears in the view respectively.

Scroll down and up to check the behavior:

```js
function isElementIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

 jQuery(document).on('scroll', function() {
     if (isElementIntoView('#theimeline')) {
         jQuery('#Layer_1_time').show();
     } else {
         jQuery('#Layer_1_time').hide();         
     }
 });
```

```css
.main {
  height: 2500px;
  padding-top: 250px;
}

#theimeline {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div id="theimeline">trigger div</div>
  <img id="Layer_1_time" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x500" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it´s just a quick-reply-answer but as far as i can read you could just add an else condition where you hide the div if scrolltop not >= theimline´s position top

```
   if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()>=jQuery('#theimeline').position().top){

       jQuery( "#Layer_1_time" ).show();
   }else{
       jQuery( "#Layer_1_time" ).hide();
   }
```